# OpenCV/C++: Copying a row/column in a Mat to another?

Tags: c++, opencv

I know I can do this by copying each element myself, but is there a method that does it for me? I tried `mat2.copyTo(mat1.row(0))` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 33):

Try

```
Mat mat1row = mat1.row(0);
mat2.copyTo(mat1row);
```

(assuming mat2 has the same size as the destination row).

That should do the job and is more clear.

Edit: This is even shorter and recommended by the official documentation:

```
A.row(j).copyTo(A.row(i));
```

More details on this in the official documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat%20Mat%3a%3arow%28int%20y%29%20const

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
destMat.row(i) = (sourceMat.row(i) + 0);
```

It's not very pretty but it gets the job done.  Also see  [this](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#Mat::row).  Read the comments on Mat::row

Comment: Did you test this thoroughly? I'm not sure, but from my understanding of OpenCV Mat, I'd say this only changes some Mat-headers and doesn't actually copy the data.

Comment: Ah, it does work, because with the "+ 0" you turn the rhs from just a header into an expression.